# Best language to program on linux embedded

Tags: c#, c, sqlite, programming-languages, embedded

I have an industrial computer (1Ghz processor, 1GB RAM) with linux embedded and I'm trying to figure out what's the best programming technology for the system we're going to develop.

System will have to read some data sent to the serial port, store it on a queue and send it back to the server, so we might need a relational embedded database...

I've read about C when you have very limited resources, but maybe this is not the case...

so far I have 2 prefered options: C or C# with Mono project.

it seems best embedded database is SQLLite.

What do you think?, any better alternative?

Comment: Why would you need a relational DB for this - is reliable storage of the data important?  Do you have another machine that it would make more sense to store the data on, rather than the embedded device itself?

Comment: It'll be a backup strategy, data will be stored on industrial computer and sent to the server to be stored there too.

Comment: It also will use DB to store the data queue

Comment: That doesn't qualify as "very limited resources".  Having less than 64k of RAM, that's limited resources.  Very limited resources is less than one kilobyte of RAM.

Comment: yes, that's why I said is not my case @Ben Voigt

Comment: @Milox: I'm just saying a DB is sort of a mismatch for a simple data queue.  You're mixing a robust and complicated technology with a very low level programming concept.  If this is for automating a high-level architectural process (e.g. multi-server task queue) it might make sense, but if you're just streaming collected data, then a DB on the collection machine is way overkill, and might cause a lot of undesirable thought and possibly performance overhead.  Something like non-volatile memory storage makes more sense to me (e.g. a memory-mapped file).

Comment: If you dump a PC into a metal cabinet, it doesn't suddenly get "embedded". Since this sounds just like another flavour of a desktop computer, use whatever you would use on an equivalent PC.

Comment: Just use whatever would work on any Linux...

Answer (score 4):

**SqlLite3**: Yes, definitely a good candidate

**C or C++** (remember: they're *different* - VERY different): both strong candidates

**[Mono/C#](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/is-mono-dead-is-novell-dying/8821)**: Not so much :)

**Java**: If there's a JVM readily available for your host, and assuming your CPU is 32 bit (or greater), then [Java JME](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/overview/getstarted/index.html) is also an option.

I'd vote either C or C++, depending on your preferences.

If you went with C++ and needed a GUI, I'd consider [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-embedded-linux/).

I strongly recommend this book:

- [Embedded Linux Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137017839), Christopher Hallinan

Comment: why, wouldn't you recommend c#?

Comment: @Milox: Probably because you said "embedded".  Your system is VERY powerful as far as embedded systems go.

Comment: Java JVM and Mono are about the same size.

Answer (score 4):

I would pick C++ cause you have a greater possibility of expressing yourself plus without any overhead.

Answer (score 1):

C, C++ or you can try D.
VM's languages like C# or Java, I don't think that should be a good option if you need low-level work with serial port.